# Android Launch timeout has expired

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I tried to start Activity from other Activity

```
startActivity(Main.this,Game.class);
```

and when Game activity is show on the screen after 1-2 sec its go left and make black screen and its write this warning

```
05-17 10:07:24.819: WARN/ActivityManager(73): 
    Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
05-17 10:07:24.849: WARN/ActivityManager(73): 
    Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40968180 game.android.test/.Game}
```

what I can to fix?

Comment: Show your onCreate() function for your game.android.test.Game Activity.

Comment: that is GL functionable, Game activity works perfectly when start at the lancher but its appear only when start from Main activity